# Prevent user from editing cell, except for actual cell data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using to keep track of when reports are sent to me.  For those reports I don't receive, I have a black cell (a cell filled black).  Locking cells doesn't really work, since they can't change the data in the cells. (Full disclosure, it's a conditional format doing the filling, if the cell has "Client" in the cell, it fills black).

How can I prevent users from changing the "client" cells?  Some of the cells aren't black, others are.  I know there's a `Worksheet_Change` that I could use, but I can't quite get that to determine the cell color *before* the user changes it.

I was thinking I'd need perhaps a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event?

The crux is I can't think of a way to check a cell's fill color *before* a change, and if it's different *after* the change, do a messagebox or whatever. (Actually, I'd be checking if the cell was "Client" before the user changed it, and if so, don't allow a change).

Am I overthinking this and missing something obvious?  I'd like to find a solution where I don't just program which cells are filled, and check if those cells were changed.

Edit: I just thought to try and combining those two `Change` events, and this seems to work, but I am not sure if it's the best way to do this:
(This is in the worksheet module)

```
Option Explicit
Dim isClient As Boolean

Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Column = 5 Or target.Column = 6 Then
    If target.Value = "Client" Then
        isClient = True
    Else
        isClient = False
    End If
End If
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Column = 5 Or target.Column = 6 And isClient = True Then
    Debug.Print "This has 'client'"
    target.Value = "Client"
    isClient = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not place the state of the cell in a public variable on selection change then check it against that variable on change.

Comment: @ScottCraner - See my edit, I think that's what you were thinking, no? I just thought of it after realizing I could use both `SelectionChange` and regular `Change`.

Comment: You would know better but it seems that it is the best way to me.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Since these are `Change` events, is there any additional caution I should take? Do I need to do anything else to reduce any overhead this might take up? I'd like to tighten it up as much as I can.

Comment: I would put a disable events in your worksheet_change but other than that it pretty straight forward.

Comment: @ScottCraner - When would I enable them again? After the code in there, or does it automatically enable after it runs? (Which I don't think it does)

Comment: No you would need to re enable it before exiting the worksheet_change.  It will not do it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

To know the old color before changing we can use `Application.Undo`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
  Dim newValue As Variant
  If target.Column = 5 Or target.Column = 6 Then

   newValue = target.Value
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Debug.Print target.Value 'old value
    Debug.Print target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color 'old color
    'if it_is_OK then target.Value = newValue
   Application.EnableEvents = True

  End If
End Sub
```

Or simply you can lock the cell when its value changed to "Client" :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

  If target.Column = 5 Or target.Column = 6 And target.Value = "Client" Then

    target.Worksheet.Unprotect
     target.Locked = True
    target.Worksheet.Protect

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: After using `.Undo`, does the `Target` refer to the "undone" value?  Ah, so `.Undo` literally undoes the change on the sheet, which you can see? I'll take a look, thanks! I'm just hesitant, for some reason I can't really say, to use `.Undo` within VB.

Comment: @BruceWayne, you are right but I don't think there is another way to know the old value.